# R loop does not update dataframe despite working from console

Tags: r, dataframe, foreach

I haven't seen any posts here with just updating existing "cells" in the dataframe (mostly creating new rows with loops), so I don't think my question is a duplicate.

I have two lists of dataframes, and I want to store a count of certain rows matching in a new dataframe.

```
countDf <- data.frame(row.names = twelve_special, count = rep(0,12)) # create empty dataframe with the 12 specific rows we want to check match

countMatchingRows <- function(dataframe1, dataframe2) {
  for (i in 1:nrow(dataframe1)) {
    if (dataframe1[i,] < 0.05 && dataframe2[i,] < 0.05) {
      print("HERE") # this prints multiple times during my run
      countDf[i,] = countDf[i,] + 1 # but this does not seem to update the dataframe counts
    }
  }
}

for (i in 1:num_runs) {
  countMatchingRows(dataframe_list_1[[i]], dataframe_list_2[[i]])
}
```

However, when I run `countDf[1,] = countDf[1,] + 1` in the console, and check countDf, the dataframe is updated. I have tried using `<-` instead of `=`, as well. I have also tried using row names in the countMatchingRows loop as well to no avail.

Comment: In R, functions should `return()` their results, and if you want the results saved you need to assign them with `<-` or `=`. If I have `x <- 1:10` and I want to see the logarithm, I can do `log(x)` and the result is returned and printed but `x` is not changed. If I want to update `x` to be the logarithm I use `x <- log(x)`.

Comment: Your function should work the same way - it should take in all the arguments it needs (not depend on a data frame named `countDf` being in the global environment), and it should return the updated result either by putting `countDf` on the last line of the function. Then if you want to update `countDf`, you would run `countDf <- countMatchingRows(dataframe_list_1[[i]], dataframe_list_2[[i]], countDf)`. (Alternately, if you always want to start with a empty `countDf` data frame, then *don't* pass it as an argument and create the empty data frame as the first line inside the function.)

Comment: That said, your function looks very inefficient - you could probably do the same thing 100 to 1000x faster and with shorter code if you used vectorization. If you ask a new question about how to do what you're doing and provide a little sample input and desired output we can help you improve the function. It might be as simple as `data.frame(row.names = twelve_special, count = rowSums(dataframe1 < 0.05 & dataframe2 < 0.05))`, but it's hard to be sure without sample inputs and expected output.